# Laravel 5.8 showing 404 Not Found errors

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I change the index.php file path public to root. After adding a .htaccess file in the root path (laravel 5.7) every page working fine. But in laravel 5.8 when I click another page, it's showing 404 Not Found.

My .htaccess file is below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
#Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d``
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of a Laravel .htaccess file should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
         Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Your webroot has to be set to the /public directory. Don't try to search for other solutions that move the index.php and .htaccess file from /public to the root directory of your Laravel application. There is absolutely no reason why you want to move the webroot from /public to /. index.php sits in /public for a reason. If your webhost does not offer the ability to move the web root to another directory switch your hoster.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have created your folder as Example and trying to access it via example
ie

```
localhost/Example/public
```

yet accessing it like

```
localhost/example/public
```